# Using jquery how to print the selected value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Below is my code that shows movie data from the JSON variable, and displays it on the drop down list based on the selected city.

I need to show the when user select the movie in movies drop down to print the movie name and theaters list as well as theater drop down..

and select one drop down another drop down don't change(when user select the movie drop down the theater drop down is default state as well as another )

below is my html

```
<div class="UserData">
        <h1><a href="moviebooking.html">MyMovie-Ticket-Booking</a></h1>
        <select class="selectCity" id="selectCity">
            <option value="">Select City</option>
            <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
            <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
            <option value="Guntur">Guntur</option>
            <option value="Ongole">Ongole</option>
        </select>
        <span id="welcome"> </span>
        <p id="demo" class="cityName"></p>
    </div>
     <div class="MoviesList" id="List">
        <label class="TitleName">Movie Name:</label>
        <select id="thirdselectbox" class="TheaterList">
             <option selected="selected"> Select Movie </option>
        </select>
        <label class="TitleName">Theater Name:</label>
        <select id="secondselectbox" class="MovieList">
             <option selected="selected"> Select Theater </option>
        </select>
      <fieldset class="Container">
        <legend class="selection">Your Selection</legend>
        <div class="TmName">
            Theater: <span id="selectedTheater"></span>
            <div id="showTimings" style="width: 30%;margin: 0 auto;">
                <!--<button class="movieTimings"></button>
                <button class="movieTimings"></button>
                <button class="movieTimings"></button>
                <button class="movieTimings"></button>-->
            </div>
            Movie: <span id="selectedMovie"></span>
        </div>
     </fieldset>
    </div>
```

below is my js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var cityData = [
    {
        cityName: 'Bengaluru',
        value: 'Bengaluru',
        data: [
            {
                movieName: 'ABC',
                theaterName: 'Tulsi Theatre',
                showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
            },
            {
                movieName: 'DEF',
                theaterName: 'PVR',
                showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
            },
            {
                movieName: 'GHI',
                theaterName: 'Srinivasa Theatre',
                showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        cityName: 'Hyderabad',
        value: 'Hyderabad',
        data: [
            {
                movieName: '123',
                theaterName: 'Theatre1',
                showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
            },
            {
                movieName: '456',
                theaterName: 'PVR2',
                showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
            },
            {
                movieName: '789',
                theaterName: 'Theatre3',
                showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
            },
        ],
    },

    {
        cityName: 'Guntur',
        value: 'Guntur',
        data: [
            {
                movieName: 'ABC1',
                theaterName: 'Theatre4',
                showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
            },
            {
                movieName: 'DEF2',
                theaterName: 'PVR3',
                showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
            },
            {
                movieName: 'GHI3',
                theaterName: 'Theatre5',
                showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
            },
        ],
    },

    {
        cityName: 'Ongole',
        value: 'Ongole',
        data: [],
    },
];

var locations = [] ;
$('#selectCity').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val().indexOf('City') === -1) {
    locations = cityData.filter( c => c.cityName === $(this).val(),)[0].data;
        var locationString = '';
        var locationString2 = '';

        if(locations.length == 0){
          $('#showTimings').html('No shows available');
        }

        $.each(locations, function(i, item) {
            locationString +='<option value="' +item.theaterName +'">' +item.theaterName +'</option>';
            locationString2 +='<option value="' +item.movieName +'">' +item.movieName +'</option>';

            $('#showTimings').html('');
            $.each(locations[i].showTImings,function(i,v){
              var button = $('<button />').html(v);
              $('#showTimings').append(button);
            });
        });
        $('#secondselectbox').html(locationString);
        $('#thirdselectbox').html(locationString2);
        $('span#selectedMovie').text($('#thirdselectbox').val());
        $('span#selectedTheater').text($('#secondselectbox').val());


    }
});

$('#secondselectbox').on('change', function() {
    var theater = $(this).val();
    for(var i in locations){
        if(locations[i].theaterName===theater){
            $('span#selectedTheater').text(theater);
            $('span#selectedMovie').text(locations[i].movieName);
            $('#thirdselectbox').val(locations[i].movieName);

            $('#showTimings').html('');
            $.each(locations[i].showTImings,function(i,v){
              var button = $('<button />').html(v);
              $('#showTimings').append(button);
            });
        }
    }


});

$('#thirdselectbox').on('change', function() {
    var movie = $(this).val();
    for(var i in locations){
        if(locations[i].movieName===movie){
            $('span#selectedMovie').text(movie);
            $('span#selectedTheater').text(locations[i].theaterName);
            $('#secondselectbox').val(locations[i].theaterName);

            $('#showTimings').html('');
            $.each(locations[i].showTImings,function(i,v){
              var button = $('<button />').html(v);
              $('#showTimings').append(button);
            });



        }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: *`print`*? Using a printer, in the console, or `document.write`?

Comment: when user select the movie in movie drop down to print the movie name and theater list as well as selection of theater....@ Adelin

Comment: Using a printer, in the console, or `document.write`?

Comment: i want print in dom how to do that one can please tell me@ Adelin

Comment: Since you're using jquery, read about [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: I dont get what you want to do with the movies and the theaters. You select a city, the movie name and theater dropdowns change, but what do you want after it? Add a table of movie-theater pairs, or list below, under the dropdowns?

Comment: you can get the selected movie name from movie dropdown , then filter your Json result based on the movie name . Next step is loop through your filtered result and then you can append the data in to your desired html like div,dropdown etc

Comment: i can do that one just now but i want when selecting movies drop down the theater drop goes to default state as well as theaters drop down select how to do that one @  Adelin